# Flatten a DIAMETER .PCAP file to text

Tags: c#, json, parsing, wireshark, pcap

I have a PCAP file containing multiple frames with the following protocols: null:ip:tcp:diameter. I would like to flatten it to text.

**Actual nonoptimal solution:**

After setting my Wireshark to decode DIAMETER packages and converting the .PCAP file to .JSON, I run a small C# program that parses the JSON to multiple C# "Frame" text objects.

Example for one "frame" object:

```
frame.number: 37
frame.encap_type: 15
frame.time: May 25, 2023 15:34:13.906377104 Hora estándar central (México)
frame.offset_shift: 0.000000000
frame.time_epoch: 1685050453.906377104
frame.time_delta: 0.045249555
frame.time_delta_displayed: 0.045249555
frame.time_relative: 685.737007346
frame.len: 1304
frame.cap_len: 1304
frame.marked: 0
frame.ignored: 0
frame.protocols: null:ip:tcp:diameter
frame.coloring_rule.name: TCP
frame.coloring_rule.string: tcp
diameter.version: 0x01
diameter.length: 1248
diameter.flags: 0xc0
diameter.cmd.code: 272
diameter.applicationId: 4
diameter.hopbyhopid: 0x18027893
diameter.endtoendid: 0x18553069
diameter.answer_in: 38
diameter.CC-Total-Octets: ESTE FRAME NO TRAE ESTE CAMPO
diameter.CC-Input-Octets: 40
diameter.CC-Output-Octets: 75
diameter.Result-Code: ESTE FRAME NO TRAE ESTE CAMPO
diameter.3GPP-Reporting-Reason: 2
diameter.CC-Time: ESTE FRAME NO TRAE ESTE CAMPO
diameter.Rating-Group: 1
```

**Another example**

```
frame.number: 39
frame.encap_type: 15
frame.time: May 25, 2023 16:11:37.618922277 Hora estándar central (México)
frame.offset_shift: 0.000000000
frame.time_epoch: 1685052697.618922277
frame.time_delta: 2243.658997427
frame.time_delta_displayed: 2243.658997427
frame.time_relative: 2929.449552519
frame.len: 1364
frame.cap_len: 1364
frame.marked: 0
frame.ignored: 0
frame.protocols: null:ip:tcp:diameter
frame.coloring_rule.name: TCP
frame.coloring_rule.string: tcp
diameter.version: 0x01
diameter.length: 1308
diameter.flags: 0xc0
diameter.cmd.code: 272
diameter.applicationId: 4
diameter.hopbyhopid: 0x1802db34
diameter.endtoendid: 0x18199300
diameter.answer_in: 40
diameter.CC-Total-Octets: 5831
diameter.CC-Input-Octets: 1361
diameter.CC-Output-Octets: 4470
diameter.Result-Code: ESTE FRAME NO TRAE ESTE CAMPO
diameter.3GPP-Reporting-Reason: HAY VARIOS VALORES EN EL FRAME, SON LOS SIGUIENTES: "3", "5",
diameter.CC-Time: 164
diameter.Rating-Group: 44
```

Multiply this for n frames...

Having these objects is very useful because we can extract only specific required values, raise alarms if a specific value is found, etc.

**The problem:**

The actual scenario works, but converting a big PCAP to a HUGE. JSON file is slow, cumbersome, and not immune to parsing errors. Maybe I'm reinventing the wheel here. Is there a simpler, faster way to accomplish what I'm doing?

PS: If Wireshark doesn't provide a solution and you need my C# program for any reason, I can share it with pleasure.

PS: Already tried some C# libraries to parse .PCAP files, but these don't recognize DIAMETER packages